# Can't get Extract-text-webpack-plugin to work for webpack in production

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, extracttextwebpackplugin

I am trying to compile `sass/scss` to css for production.

Essentially I was wondering how can you create a file structure for your assets in prod and get the scss files to get complied to css in prod? I have seen in many TUTs, everything gets dumped in a `dist`or `public folder`. I can do it for JS, but how would you do it for all my assets?  Example in the public folder there is a `JS folder a image folder, css` etc.

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/js/app.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './public',
        port: 8888
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
              test: /\.scss$/, 
              use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use : 'css-loader!sass-loader'
              })

            }
        ]
      },
    plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ]
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell based on the provided webpack output, it spit out the styles.css file correctly. Please check `public/js` folder.

EDIT: Just noticed you edited the question. You can change the `output.path` to be just `public` and then you should be able to change the configuration of ExtractTextPlugin to write the styles into `css/styles.css`. Same for `output.filename` when it comes to JS build artifacts.

Comment: @MarekSuscak Thanks for the info but I can't seem to get that suggestion to work?

Comment: Check out this test repo I set up for you (instructions in readme): https://github.com/mareksuscak/webpack-so-1

Comment: That worked my friend! You saved some hair on my head from being pulled out!